# Stacked Graphs in Kibana 3

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I have indexed some data and is made available in localhost. So i need to do some analytics on this data which includes graphical analysis. I need to do stacked graph analytics for different queries as shown in the below example graph.
[image]

I have been trying to get this graph,but all I can get was only one bar graph. How can i get the stacked graphs for multiple queries using Kibana 3?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First you need to create a histogram graph. Note that the Time Field should be set at the time stamp which you have in your index.
2) Search a query in the query panel. Here I have searched for "wolverine" and this is what my histogram looks like.
[image]

3) Then search for another query by pressing the "+" button to the right of the search button shown in the figure below. I have my second query as "hulk" as shown in the below pic. Then press the search button. The resulting histogram is a stacked one as below.
image: kibana 3-03

You can find more information on multi query histogram [here](http://blog.qbox.io/advanced-kibana-analytics-part-4-of-series).

[image]